# Bootstrap 3 modal in mozilla not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey guys I'm using bootstrap v3.3.7 and I made bootstrap modal now everything works fine on chrome and safari, but for some reason it doesn't work on mozilla. When I press modal button in mozilla nothing happens. This is my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg accountBtn">
    <a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal">Account details</a>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h2>Header h2</h2>
                <h3>Header h3</h3>
                <ul class="characteristicsList">
                    Characteristics:
                    <li><img src="images/modal1.png" alt="">Property: </li>
                    <li><img src="images/modal2.png" alt="">Property: </li>
                    <li><img src="images/modal3.png" alt="">Property: </li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg buyBtn">
                    <a href="myPaypalLink" target="_blank">Buy Now X$</a>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also my button with "a" tag which I use in my modal and also without modal in my html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg buyBtn">
    <a href="myPaypalLink" target="_blank">Buy Now X$</a>
</button>
```

doesn't work in mozilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong to put an anchor tag `a` inside a `button` tag. Just use anchor tag altogether and everything will work fine.

```
<a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-lg accountBtn">
    Account details
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you works great can I ask why is this a problem in mozilla but works good in chrome ?

Comment: I'm not so sure, but I think the way each browser implements the `html` standards differ. So, some will be very strict,  while some others will try to implement your code as much as possible